# How to map a list with sections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list

I have this array of data, and I'm trying to list them with sections, already knew how to use .map to list the array, but failed to list each list item under it's section, instead I had to use .map with each section.

**Section 1 Data (Dashboard):**

```
const DashboardListItems = [
    {
      name: "Home",
      to: "/",
      icon: LineStyleIcon
    },
    {
      name: "Analytics",
      to: "/analytics",
      icon: TimelineIcon
    },
  ];
```

**Section 2 Data (QuickMenu):**

```
const QuickMenuListItems = [
    {
      name: "Users",
      to: "/users",
      icon: PermIdentityIcon
    },

    {
      name: "Posts",
      to: "/posts",
      icon: AssignmentIcon
    },

    {
      name: "Coupons",
      to: "/coupons",
      icon: DiscountIcon
    },

    {
      name: "Shops",
      to: "/shops",
      icon: StoreIcon
    },

    {
      name: "Products",
      to: "/products",
      icon: StorefrontIcon
    },

    {
      name: "Transactions",
      to: "/transactions",
      icon: AttachMoneyIcon
    },

    {
      name: "Reports",
      to: "/reports",
      icon: BarChartIcon
    },
  ];
```

**The Code:**

```
    <div className="sidebarMenu">
      <h3 className="sidebarTitle">Dashboard</h3>
      <ul className="sidebarList">
        {DashboardListItems.map((dashboardListItems, index) => {
          const Icon = dashboardListItems.icon;
        return (
          <Link to={dashboardListItems.to} className="link">
          <li
            onClick={() => setActiveIndex(index)}
            className={`sidebarListItem ${
              index === activeIndex ? "active" : ""}`}>
            <Icon className="sidebarIcon"/>
            {dashboardListItems.name}
          </li>
          </Link>
        );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I had to use it twice for the other section, the question is how avoid this ?

Comment: If you want to avoid writing the same code for the other array you separate out that JSX into its own component, and then call it (passing in the relevant array) from the different sections of your app.

Answer (score 0):

let me help you out:

1. If you want the data to be shown on the webpage you have to iterate both variables using map, because if you use forEach you can iterate the data but nothing is returned, so it can't be displayed without using map.
2. I think the proper way of performing this is using a component or a function where you can pick the props of the data and processing it, but in any case you will need to do both loops to pass the data stored in QuickMenuList and DashboardListItems.

   function processElement({name, to, icon}){
   //process data
   }

Another way to deal with this is declaring both variables as one, instead of declaring the data inside 2 variables just use one, they have the same props.

I hope it helps you :)